# ActionBar Tab Width

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I've been trying to find out how to edit the tab width in the action bar.

I'm running an app on my Gnexus and although the tabs in Portrait are of satisfying width, I'd like them to be wider in Landscape mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying different styles in your application. This question
[Android - customizing actionbar sherlock tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853344/android-customizing-actionbar-sherlock-tabs)

mentions your problem very detailed.

greetings