# Android ActionBar: padding left of first tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm having a problem with my ActionBar tabs (using ActionBarSherlock). The problem only appears on post Gingerbread though.

When the tabs are in stacked mode (as in 2 a 2-lined ActionBar) there's a padding on the left which moves the tabs to the right. It's half the width of my divider - if I change my dividerwidth the width changes too, if I remove it completely everything's working as intended. I have set `android:showDividers="middle"` in my theme, so that's not the problem.

It wouldn't be a problem if I wouldn't have 2 tabs and some Buttons below them, which fill up half of the screens, so you can see that there's an offset in my tabs.

Here's a picture of it:[image]

As you can see there's a small gap next to the left tab selector, which results in the tab being bigger. The asset doesn't have any padding on it, the problem doesn't appear on the right tab.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: try to use the native `ActionBar`, to know if the problem is fron `Sherlock` or the native one.

Comment: can u share the picture of your actionbar? If my guess is correct u should refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853344/android-customizing-actionbar-sherlock-tabs

Comment: @Infusion-Apps.comt: I've just created a small test project with the standard actionbar, but it doesn't seem to happen (I didn't start to style though...). I still have doubts that it's ActionbarSherlock, as it's not happening on pre-honeycomb.

Comment: @Raghav: I've added a picture of it.

Comment: @Maria Neumayer , Hey Maria did you find the solution for this?