# ActionBarSherlock: Tab loses custom view in landscape mode

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm using ActionBarSherlock with `NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS`. Each tab contains a custom view. While it looks fine in portrait mode, there are numerous problems in landscape mode if the tabs are displayed as drop down list (automatically done by Android):

- Android 4.x: The selected tab is not shown in the Action Bar (see image, red circle). The same happens when using the built-in Action Bar from the Android SDK directly.
- Android 2.x: The selected tab is not shown in the Action Bar. As soon as I click on the drop down, the whole drop down vanishes and I get empty tabs instead.

[image: Action Bar not showing selected tab]

Everything works fine if I do not use a custom view. My code that creates the ActionBar on the image (kept simple on purpose):

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = getActionBar().newTab();
    TextView view = new TextView(this);
    view.setText("This is tab " + (i + 1));
    tab.setCustomView(view);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    getActionBar().addTab(tab);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**: To clarify, `getSupportActionBar()` is present in the original code and the Action Bar from ActionBarSherlock is working fine apart from the described issues. I used the code sample above to illustrate that the first issue (selected tab not shown in Action Bar) is also present when using the built-in Action Bar. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

With ActionBarSherlock you should be using `getSupportActionBar()` in order for it to work on 2.x

```
getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
    tab.setText("Tab " + i);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
}
```

The text color is either coming from the custom view you are applying to the Tab or from a theme you are applying at the Activity level.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Regarding `getSupportActionBar()`, please see my edit. Regarding the text color (black on black): A custom style does not seem to be issue. This is the stock Holo theme without any customizations. If I switch to Holo.Light, the ActionBar still does not show the selected tab.

Answer (score 0):

this method works fine for me:

JUST PUT THE NAVIGATION METHOD, AFTER ADDING ADDING TABS:

```
... // adding tabs
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.Navigation_mode_tabs);
```

goodLuck ;)