# Changing the font on ActionBar tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to figure out how to change the font on actionbar tabs to some custom font, and for the life of me I can't figure it out. IT doesn't seem like there is any way to access the underlying TextView of a Tab object.

The *other* solution of course, is to define my own custom ActionBar tab layout, and set it as a custom view on the ActionBar.Tab object, but this seems quite tricky to get working also.

If I were to use the following XML layout file as my custom tab layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_tab"
        style="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The actionbar tab seems to be ignoring all of my gravity requests, and positioning the text at the top of the tab view -- which is quite different to a standard actionbar tab which has the text centered vertically by default.

If anyone could suggest either a) an easier way of supplying a custom Typeface for an actionbar tab or b) the correct layout for a custom tab view I would be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665186/change-font-style-in-action-bar-tabs-using-sherlock

Comment: It still leaves the ActionBar.Tab text top-aligned, which is not what I want. The standard actionbar tab text is centered vertically.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's possible unfortunately. Here's why:
Like you, I tried using a`TextView`centered in a`RelativeLayout`as a custom view for my tabs using`ActionBar.Tab.setCustomView()`method. I used`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`and`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`on the`RelativeLayout`so normally the`TextView`should be centered in it. So then I tried with only a`TextView`not wrapped in a`RelativeLayout`like so:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TAB_TITLE" />
```

So normally the`TextView`should completely fill the Tab and the text should be centered inside it. However that's still not the case: the text is still not centered vertically. So I decided to add`android:background="#ffffff"` to the`TextView`so I can see what's happening. Thanks to the background, I realized that the`ActionBar.Tab.setCustomView()`method does not set a custom layout for the tab, but rather sets a custom view inside another layout to which we do not have access (AFAIK). It makes sense that`android:layout_width="fill_parent"`and`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`are ignored in my`TextView`since I use`null`as the parent when inflating the tab layout. So to center the text in the`TextView`I programmatically set the height of the`TextView`to a very high value so it fills its parent. Then the text is centered vertically. Note that you could also use top padding to create the same effect. Here's my code:

custom_tab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tab_title"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="TAB_TITLE" />
```

Code in my activity to set the custom view:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    TextView customTabView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
    customTabView.setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i));
    // set the height to a really high value to fill the parent
    customTabView.setHeight(999);
    tab.setCustomView(customTabView);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

If anyone knows how to access the parent view of the set custom view, let me know. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative layout. The linear layout dont let to use 
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical".... It only lets using center horizontal..

If you use relative layout, you could use

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either, I tried setting the `RelativeLayout` to `match_parent` and setting `layout_centerInParent` to true, but it didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set your layout_width and layout_height to "fill_parent" not to wrap_content
such:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

so that your text can be centered.

Answer (score 0):

First look at this example:
[http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/][1]

then create a layout and name it tab_title with the following code:

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/action_custom_title"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Custom title"
android:textColor="#fff"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:paddingTop="5dp" />
```

Then simply in onCreate() method of MainActivity of Androidhive project, just change:

```
 // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
```

To:

```
// Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {

        Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
        TextView customTabView = (TextView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_title, null);
        customTabView.setText(tab_name);
        Typeface typface2=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/titr.TTF");
        customTabView.setTypeface(typface2);            
        tab.setTabListener(this);           
        tab.setCustomView(customTabView);
        actionBar.addTab(tab);
    }
```

(No need to say that you have to change fonts/titr.TTF to your asset directory and filename)
Joint it!!