# Change the font of tab text in android design support TabLayout

Tags: android, fonts, android-design-library, android-fonts, android-tablayout

I'm trying to work on the new `TabLayout` from the android design library.

I want to change tab text to **custom font**. And,I tried to search some styling related to `TabLayout`,but ended up to [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/values/styles.xml).

Please guide how can I change the tab text fonts.

Comment: Use Spannable String

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Create a TextView from Java Code or XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@color/tabs_default_color"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

Make sure to keep the id as it is here because the TabLayout check for this ID if you use custom textview

Then from code inflate this layout and set the custom `Typeface` on that textview and add this custom view to the tab

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
     //noinspection ConstantConditions
     TextView tv = (TextView)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab,null)
     tv.setTypeface(Typeface);       
     tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);
}
```

Comment: How can I set `tabTextColor` and `tabSelectedTextColor` property in this situation?

Comment: I get the solution from [praveen Sharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31067431/6444297)

Answer (score 174):

If you are using `TabLayout` and you want to change the font you have to add a new for loop to the previous solution like this:

```
private void changeTabsFont() {
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Font.getInstance().getTypeFace(), Typeface.NORMAL);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to [change font style in action bar tabs using sherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665186/change-font-style-in-action-bar-tabs-using-sherlock)

Comment: I am not using M preview. Is there any other way to do it.

Comment: You don't need M preview, it is valid for everyone using `TabLayout`

Comment: However, I'm encountering a NullPointerException on android.view.View android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.getChildAt(int), can you help me how to fix it? Can't find what am I missing on my code.

Comment: The first parameter of `setTypeFace` is a `TypeFace`, in case if you can't find the `Font` class (which doesn't appear to exist for me)

Answer (score 152):

Create your own custom style and use parent style as `parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"`

And in your tab layout use this style as `app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text"`

Example:
Style:

```
<style name="tab_text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
</style>
```

Example: Tab layout component:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/tab_text" />
```

Comment: This is correct, I'm using `parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab"` in my case.

Comment: This works much better than first answers, and without black magic (hidden api), which could break something in the future

Comment: just work when use fontFamily, not work when use fontPath

Comment: I was getting weird exceptions erratically when using `TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget`. @Javatar 's answer fixed it for me.

Comment: I'm using `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` so my style's parent is `Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout`, other than that same solution, works great, thanks.

Answer (score 49):

Great answer from praveen Sharma. Just a small addition:
Instead of using `changeTabsFont()` everywhere you need `TabLayout`, you can simply use your own `CustomTabLayout`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private Typeface mTypeface;

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(Tab tab) {
        super.addTab(tab);

        ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
        ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) mainView.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());

        int tabChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And one more thing.
`TabView` is a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` inside (it can also optionally contain `ImageView`). So you can make the code even simpler:

```
@Override
public void addTab(Tab tab) {
    super.addTab(tab);

    ViewGroup mainView = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
    ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) mainView.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
    View tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(1);
    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(mTypeface, Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

But I wouldn't recommend this way. If `TabLayout` implementation will change, this code can work improperly or even crash.

Another way to customise `TabLayout` is adding custom view to it. Here is the great [example](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout#add-custom-view-to-tablayout).

Comment: addTab wiil not invoke in case you set tabs like this: mViewPager.setAdapter(new YourPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

Comment: @Penzzz you are absolutely right. In this case you should move the code from addTab method to another. For example onMeasure.

Comment: @AndreiAulaska thnx You save my day . Your last Link save me.

Comment: this does not work anymore i think in latest version. @ejw's answer is now working. need to add it in addTab(Tab tab, boolean setSelected)

Comment: This works well. NOTE: as of support library 25.x, you need to override `addTab(Tab tab, int position, boolean setSelected)` instead of `addTab(Tab tab)`.

Answer (score 31):

To use fonts support in `XML` feature on devices running `Android 4.1` (API level 16) and higher, use the Support Library 26+.

1. Right click res folder
2. New -> Android resource directory-> select font -> Ok
3. Put your `myfont.ttf` file in newly created font folder

On `res/values/styles.xml` add:

```
<style name="customfontstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/myfont</item>
</style>
```

On layout file add app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customfontstyle",

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/customfontstyle"
    app:tabMode="fixed" />
```

Please refer to [fonts in xml].(https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

Comment: it works on xamarin forms and xamarin android.thanks

Comment: Great answer! Should extend "TextAppearance.Design.Tab" though

Comment: Simple answer better than the others. Note: if you want the text in all caps use ```parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab"``` otherwise ```@android:style/TextAppearance.Small``` works

Answer (score 22):

If you are using

> com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0 (latest version)

```
<style name="MyCustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="fontFamily">Your Font</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">Your Font</item>
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    </style>

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabTextAppearance"
        app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 16):

The following method will change font in entire `ViewGroup` recursively. I chose this method because you don't have to care about inner structure of `TabLayout`. I'm using [Calligraphy](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) library to set a font.

```
void changeFontInViewGroup(ViewGroup viewGroup, String fontPath) {
    for (int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
        if (TextView.class.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            CalligraphyUtils.applyFontToTextView(child.getContext(), (TextView) child, fontPath);
        } else if (ViewGroup.class.isAssignableFrom(child.getClass())) {
            changeFontInViewGroup((ViewGroup) viewGroup.getChildAt(i), fontPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: problem with this is, if you attach the layout to a Viewpager, you will lose the customized fonts.

Answer (score 11):

As **Andrei** answered, you can change fontface by extending **TabLayout** class. And as **Penzzz** said, you can't do it in **addTab** method. Override **onLayout** method as bellow:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom){
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    final ViewGroup tabStrip = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
    final int tabCount = tabStrip.getChildCount();
    ViewGroup tabView;
    int tabChildCount;
    View tabViewChild;

    for(int i=0; i<tabCount; i++){
        tabView = (ViewGroup)tabStrip.getChildAt(i);
        tabChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
        for(int j=0; j<tabChildCount; j++){
            tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(j);
            if(tabViewChild instanceof AppCompatTextView){
                if(fontFace == null){
                    fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.IranSans));
                }
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(fontFace, Typeface.BOLD);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Must Overwrite onLayout method, because, when you use **setupWithViewPager** method to bind the TabLayout with the ViewPager, you have to set tabs text either with setText method or in the PagerAdapter after that and when this  happened, onLayout method get called on the parent ViewGroup (TabLayout) and that's the place to put setting fontface.(Changing a TextView text cause calling onLayout method of it's parent - A tabView has two children, one is ImageView another is TextView)

**Another Solution:**

First, these lines of code:

```
    if(fontFace == null){
        fontFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), context.getString(R.string.IranSans));
    }
```

In above solution, should be written outside of two loops.

But better solution for **API >= 16** is using **android:fontFamily**:

Create a **Android Resource Directory** named font and copy your desired font to the directory.

Then use these styles:

```
<style name="tabLayoutTitles">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/appFirstFontSize</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/vazir_bold</item>
</style>

<style name="defaultTabLayout">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/defaultTabLayoutHeight</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/tabLayoutTitles</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">@dimen/accomTabIndicatorHeight</item>
    <item name="tabMode">fixed</item>
    <item name="tabGravity">fill</item>
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/rectangle_white_ripple</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: This is a bad performance fix, `onLayout()` got called with every layout change like tab switching or even list scrolling below the tabs, with nested `for`s in a many tabs `TabLayout` app will be lagy.

Comment: @Amr Barakat. According to this link: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int), this is not true. I tested it too. I put a break point  in **onLayout** method and it's get called when the tabs are being created not on tab switching or list scrolling.

Comment: For me `onLayout()` does get called multiple times when tab switching (not sure why exactly), but to account for this I only set the fonts when the `boolean changed` is true. Doing that prevents setting the fonts multiple times.

Comment: great solution, no code required, only xml attributes

Answer (score 10):

For design support 23.2.0, using setupWithViewPager, you'll have to move the code from addTab(Tab tab) to addTab(Tab tab, boolean setSelected).

Answer (score 8):

You can use this, it works for me.

```
 private void changeTabsFont() {
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                AssetManager mgr = getActivity().getAssets();
                Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mgr, "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");//Font file in /assets
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, i found it simple in 23.4.0 without using a loop. Just override addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, boolean setSelected) as suggested by @ejw.

```
@Override
public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, boolean setSelected) {
    CoralBoldTextView coralTabView = (CoralBoldTextView) View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.coral_tab_layout_view, null);
    coralTabView.setText(tab.getText());
    tab.setCustomView(coralTabView);

    super.addTab(tab, setSelected);
}
```

And here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<id.co.coralshop.skyfish.ui.CoralBoldTextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/custom_text"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:ellipsize="end"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:singleLine="true"
   android:textColor="@color/graylove"
   android:textSize="@dimen/tab_text_size" />
```

Hope it could help :)

Comment: But how to set tabSelectedTextColor and tabTextColo?

Comment: @MostafaImran your version of `android:textColor="@color/graylove"` should have the state list selector for that with state_selected color specified

Answer (score 4):

Kotlin extension that worked for me:

```
fun TabLayout.setFont(font: FontUtils.Fonts) {
    val vg = this.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    for (i: Int in 0..vg.childCount) {
        val vgTab = vg.getChildAt(i) as ViewGroup?
        vgTab?.let {
            for (j: Int in 0..vgTab.childCount) {
                val tab = vgTab.getChildAt(j)
                if (tab is TextView) {
                    tab.typeface = FontUtils.getTypeFaceByFont(FontUtils.Fonts.BOLD, context)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My Resolve method just like this ,change the Specified tab text ,

```
 ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
 ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(1);
 View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(1);
 if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
      ((TextView) tabViewChild).setText(str);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
I think this is easier way.

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
   android:id="@+id/tabs"
   app:tabTextColor="@color/lightPrimary"
   app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
   style="@style/CustomTabLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<style name="CustomTabLayout" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
   <item name="tabMaxWidth">20dp</item>
   <item name="tabMode">scrollable</item>
   <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?attr/colorAccent</item>
   <item name="tabIndicatorHeight">2dp</item>
   <item name="tabPaddingStart">12dp</item>
   <item name="tabPaddingEnd">12dp</item>
   <item name="tabBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>
   <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/CustomTabTextAppearance</item>
   <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">?android:textColorPrimary</item>
</style>
<style name="CustomTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
   <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
   <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">?android:textColorSecondary</item>
   <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

And here is my implementation in Kotlin that also allow change font for selected and unselected tabs.

```
class FontTabLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    @AttrRes defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TabLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var textSize = 14f

    private var defaultSelectedPosition = 0

    private var selectedTypeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.muli_bold)
    private var normalTypeFace: Typeface? = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.muli_regular)

    @ColorInt private var selectedColor = 0
    @ColorInt private var normalTextColor = 0

    init {
        attrs?.let { initAttrs(it) }
        addOnTabSelectedListener()
    }

    private fun initAttrs(attrs: AttributeSet) {
        val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.FontTabLayout)

        textSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.FontTabLayout_textSize, 14).toFloat()

        defaultSelectedPosition = a.getInteger(R.styleable.FontTabLayout_defaultSelectedPosition, 0)
        val selectedResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.FontTabLayout_selectedTypeFace, R.font.muli_bold)
        val normalResourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.FontTabLayout_normalTypeFace, R.font.muli_regular)

        selectedColor = a.getColor(com.google.android.material.R.styleable.TabLayout_tabSelectedTextColor, 0)
        normalTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.FontTabLayout_normalTextColor, 0)

        selectedTypeFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, selectedResourceId)
        normalTypeFace = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, normalResourceId)

        a.recycle()
    }

    private fun addOnTabSelectedListener() {
        addOnTabSelectedListener(object : OnTabSelectedListenerAdapter() {

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: Tab?) {
                getCustomViewFromTab(tab)?.apply {
                    setTextColor(normalTextColor)
                    typeface = normalTypeFace
                }
            }

            override fun onTabSelected(tab: Tab?) {

                getCustomViewFromTab(tab)?.apply {
                    setTextColor(selectedColor)
                    typeface = selectedTypeFace
                }
            }

            private fun getCustomViewFromTab(tab: Tab?) = tab?.customView as? AppCompatTextView

        })
    }

    override fun setupWithViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager?, autoRefresh: Boolean) {
        super.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, autoRefresh)
        addViews(viewPager)
    }

    private fun addViews(viewPager: ViewPager?) {
        for (i in 0 until tabCount) {
            val customTabView = getCustomTabView(i).apply {
                typeface = if (i == defaultSelectedPosition) selectedTypeFace else normalTypeFace
                val color = if (i == defaultSelectedPosition) selectedColor else normalTextColor
                setTextColor(color)
                text = viewPager?.adapter?.getPageTitle(i)
            }

            getTabAt(i)?.customView = customTabView
        }
    }

    private fun getCustomTabView(position: Int): AppCompatTextView {
        return AppCompatTextView(context).apply {
            gravity = Gravity.CENTER
            textSize = this@FontTabLayout.textSize
            text = position.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

in attrs.xml:

```
<declare-styleable name="FontTabLayout">
    <attr name="normalTextColor" format="reference|color" />
    <attr name="textSize" format="dimension" />
    <attr name="defaultSelectedPosition" format="integer" />
    <attr name="selectedTypeFace" format="reference" />
    <attr name="normalTypeFace" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: tabs.getTabAt(1)?.text is not changing the text dynamically, once set.

Answer (score 2):

You can change Text Appearance of Tab icon by using this style written in style.xml file. here it is

```
<style name="TabItemTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
        <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
        <item name="fontWeight">800</item>
        <item name="fontFamily">@font/balooda2_medium</item>
</style>
```

and use this style in your TabLayout. Here it is

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/live_tab_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
                app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabItemTextAppearance"
                app:tabTextColor="#354895">

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/live_tab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="লাইভ ক্লাস" />

                <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                    android:id="@+id/recorded_tab"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="রেকর্ডেড ভিডিও" />

</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

My 2p, Kotlin with reference checking, applicable everywhere as it will stop if something is wrong.

```
private fun setTabLayouFont(tabLayout: TabLayout) {
    val viewGroupTabLayout = tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as? ViewGroup?
    (0 until (viewGroupTabLayout?.childCount ?: return))
            .map { viewGroupTabLayout.getChildAt(it) as? ViewGroup? }
            .forEach { viewGroupTabItem ->
                (0 until (viewGroupTabItem?.childCount ?: return))
                        .mapNotNull { viewGroupTabItem.getChildAt(it) as? TextView }
                        .forEach { applyDefaultFontToTextView(it) }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With kotlin extension functions use this:

```
 fun TabLayout.setFontSizeAndColor(typeface: Typeface, @DimenRes textSize: Int, @ColorRes textColor: Int) {
val viewGroup: ViewGroup = this.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
val tabsCount: Int = viewGroup.childCount
for (j in 0 until tabsCount) {
    val viewGroupTab: ViewGroup = viewGroup.getChildAt(j) as ViewGroup
    val tabChildCount: Int = viewGroupTab.childCount
    for (i in 0 until tabChildCount) {
        val tabViewChild: View = viewGroupTab.getChildAt(i) as View
        if ( tabViewChild is TextView) {
            tabViewChild.typeface = typeface
            tabViewChild.gravity = Gravity.FILL
            tabViewChild.maxLines = 1
            tabViewChild.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, this.resources.getDimension(textSize))
            tabViewChild.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, textColor))
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
fun TabLayout.customizeTabText() {
    val viewGroup = this.getChildAt(0) as ViewGroup
    for (i: Int in 0..viewGroup.childCount) {
        val tabViewGroup = viewGroup.getChildAt(i) as ViewGroup?
        tabViewGroup?.let {
            for (j: Int in 0..tabViewGroup.childCount) {
                val tab = tabViewGroup.getChildAt(j)
                if (tab is TextView) {
                    tab.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.assets, "font.ttf")
                    tab.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 21f)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    //Update Tab layout indicator and text color
            tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.GREY);
            tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.RED,Color.GREEN);
    
    //setup tablayout with view pager
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    //after set up with view pager call update font of tablayout text
            for (int a = 0; a < tabLayout.getTabCount(); a++){
                 TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(a);
                 setTabTypeface(selectedTab, ResourcesCompat.getFont(this,R.font.dancingscript_bold));
                }

    //add this function to your class 
     private void setTabTypeface(TabLayout.Tab tab, Typeface typeface){
            for(int i=0; i<tab.view.getChildCount(); i++) {
                View tabViewChild = tab.view.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView)
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

Change

`if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {`

for

```
if (tabViewChild instanceof AppCompatTextView) {
```

to make it work with android.support.design.widget.TabLayout (at least from  com.android.support:design:23.2.0)

Comment: but AppCompatTextView extends TextView, so why this would make a difference?