# How to embed font in tab layout from design support android

Tags: android, android-tablayout, font-embedding

I want to embed custom font in tablayout from design support library. I try to set custom view which is set typeface already. But it is not working. Just appear system font.

What I did is,

```
mAdpater = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mFragmentPager.setAdapter(mAdpater);
mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mFragmentPager);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myFont.ttf");
for (int i = 0; i < mTabs.getTabCount(); i++) {
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(mAdpater.getPageTitle(i));
    tv.setTypeface(tf);
    mTabs.getTabAt(i).setCustomView(tv);
}
```

Welcome for any suggestion.

Comment: setTypeface then set the text after it..

Comment: Nope .. It doesn't work and make any effect.

Answer (score 6):

If you override `getPageTitle` in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`, then call

```
mTabs.setupWithViewPager(mFragmentPager);
```

the tabs text is set for you.

Then to change the font I used this method from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31067431/3716281) SO post

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "myfont.ttf");
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the `FragmentPagerAdapter` in its entirety for reference

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> fragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        fragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return fragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just add code below

```
int wantedTabIndex = 0;

TextView tv = (TextView)(((LinearLayout)

((LinearLayout)tabLayout_main.getChildAt(0)).getChildAt(wantedTabIndex)).getChildat(1));
 tv.setText("your title");

tv.setTypeFace(customfont);
```

the wantedtabIndex in above code is your tab position