# Tablayout font not changing

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to add a font to the tablayout. The tabs are filled dynamically using Json.
Please suggest me how to add font to the tab headers.

This is the tablayout

```
private void setupPager() {
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),getContext()));
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "EdgeCaps.ttf");
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is the adapter. Here tabnames is a string array filled by json parsing.

```
 private class CustomAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public CustomAdapter(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment fragment = new ItemsMenuFragment();
            return  fragment;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabNames.size();
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabNames.get(position);
        }
    }
```

}

Can anyone help me to change the font of the tablayout.I have tried to use this in the setupPager but its not working.

```
 Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "EdgeCaps.ttf");
            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
            int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
            for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
                ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
                int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                    View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                    if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                        ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tf);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure what's going on in your code. But this class might help. All it does is set the all the TextViews inside a tab to EdgeCaps.tff whenever a new tab is added to the TabLayout.
Use it in place of a normal TabLayout and make sure that you've put your your EdgeCaps.tff font inside the "assets/fonts" directory of your project.

[Here's an example of where the font file is meant to go (using Android Studio).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeqGt.png)

Code was modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33284990/2996119) to work with Android Support Library 23.3.0:

```
public class CustomFontTabLayout extends TabLayout {
    private Typeface mCustomTypeFace;

    public CustomFontTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initialise();
    }

    public CustomFontTabLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialise();
    }

    public CustomFontTabLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialise();
    }
    private void initialise()
    {
        // Note: Rename "EdgeCaps.tff" to whatever your font file is named.
        // Note that the font file needs to be in the assets/fonts/ folder.
        mCustomTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/EdgeCaps.tff"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, boolean setSelected) {
        super.addTab(tab, setSelected);
        setTabTypeFace(tab);
    }

    @Override
    public void addTab(@NonNull Tab tab, int position, boolean setSelected) {
        super.addTab(tab, position, setSelected);
        setTabTypeFace(tab);
    }

    private void setTabTypeFace(Tab tab)
    {
        ViewGroup tabLayoutView = (ViewGroup)getChildAt(0);
        ViewGroup tabView = (ViewGroup) tabLayoutView.getChildAt(tab.getPosition());
        int tabViewChildCount = tabView.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabViewChildCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = tabView.getChildAt(i);
            // Find the TextView in the tab
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                TextView tabTextView = (TextView)tabViewChild;
                // Set the TextView's font
                tabTextView .setTypeface(mCustomTypeFace, Typeface.NORMAL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing this.. But everytime i am getting an exception that Font asset not found fonts/EdgeCaps.tff

Comment: @RohitMishra are you using do you have a font file named "EdgeCaps.tff" in the assets folder of your project?

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="NavigationTab" parent="Widget.Design.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabBackground">@drawable/background_tab</item>
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/primary_light</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/NavigationTabTextAppeareance</item>
</style>

<style name="NavigationTabTextAppeareance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/primary_light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>
```

Inside the TabLayout xml file. add this as style. change the fontsize according to what you want.

Comment: I have tried this one.. But i want a custom font "EdgeCaps.ttf" to be applied to the tablayout.How to do that via code?

Comment: This doesn't work. TextAppearance.Design.Tab is a button style and it looks like a pre-material design button cant have a custom font through styles.