# How to change material viewpager tab indicator text color?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, material-design, android-tabhost

[Here is my customized material viewpager layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bg865.jpg)

I have to change my material view pager tab indicator color and font programmatically. Please give me a solution for this.I cannot able to find any solution for this in github.

Comment: use app:tabIndicatorColor for changing tab indicator color, to change font you have to use custom fonts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For changing colour of  indicator programmatically.

```
tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#898989"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use below attribute to change the color of the indicator in tabLayout:

```
 app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
```

For custom font, refer following link:  [Change the font of tab text in android design support TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067265/change-the-font-of-tab-text-in-android-design-support-tablayout)

Answer (score 1):

To Change the color of the indicator in tabLayout:

```
 app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/your_color"
```

This is the line in my build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1' //Make sure check your version
```