# How to change tablayout font size

Tags: android, tabs

How to change Font type of android.support.design.widget.TabLayout?

I'm using style for this problem but app crashes in API 16.
Thank you.

Comment: you must create custom layout which contains textview and adapter for tablayout.

Comment: please post your code and error

Comment: after I want use this code in style.xml   crashes app in api 16  `<style name="TabFont" parent="Base.Widget.Design.TabLayout">
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="tabIndicatorColor">#FF4081</item>
    </style>`

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```
private void changeTabsFont() {

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(Font.getInstance().getTypeFace(), Typeface.NORMAL);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Mentioned on this article: [Change the font of tab text in android design support TabLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31067265/change-the-font-of-tab-text-in-android-design-support-tablayout)

Comment: Thank you. but don't work ----- Font.getInstance().getTypeFace() i'm not this code

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
private void changeTabsFont(TabLayout tabLayout) {

    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
    int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
        ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
        int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
            View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
            if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(/* your typeface */);
            }
        }
    }
}
```