# How to change font size in Material Design TabLayout android?

Tags: android, material-design, android-tablayout

I have been trying to explore online to set my font size for TabLayout TabItems
But none of them seems to be working for me. This is what I tried referring last [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45816863/7505562)

below are the things which I have implemented so far,
Not sure why it's not picking `textSize` from style.

**in xml:**

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayoutForgot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_height"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewLogo"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/text_color"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/text_color"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/text_color" />
```

**in themes.xml:**

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_color</item>
    </style>
```

this does everything else like `textAllCaps` and `fontFamily` but doesn't seems to take `textSize`.

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to find a solution to my issue.

Adding the below line of code in `dimens.xml` somehow made it work for me.

`<dimen name="design_tab_text_size_2line" tools:override="true">20sp</dimen>`

Answer (score 3):

You can customise TabLayout textColor, textSize, fontFamily etc. as below

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        //
 app:tabTextAppearance="@style/TabTextAppearance" />


<style name="TabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">#9F9F9F</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/cera_pro_medium</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should inherit your style from `TextAppearance.Design.Tab`
First make a style,

```
<style name="MyStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Then use it in your Tablayout like this,

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyStyle"
            ...
            />
```

hope it will work

Comment: Hi, I will try that btw I am using ```com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout``` and not ```android.support.design.widget.TabLayout``` Not sure if that can affect anything. But will try and update here

Comment: it will work fine, I guess. If not let me know.

Comment: its still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Try `style` to `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout`

Add `parent` of main style as `@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout`

Add `parent` of `tabTextAppearance` style as `@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView`

```
<style name="MyCustomTabLayout" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TabLayout">
    <item name="tabSelectedTextColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextColor">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="tabIndicatorColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="tabTextAppearance">@style/TabText</item>
</style>

<style name="TabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView">
    <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

In Xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
      android:id="@+id/tabLayoutForgot"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"/>
```

Comment: I get:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{.../...FragMainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #67 in ...